# LinkedHashMap: function in method?

Tags: java, inputstream, linkedhashmap

LinkedHashMap Declared as such:

```
public class Search {
    private LinkedHashMap<String, String> Pairs;
```

What is readSurnames() Method actually doing in reference to the LinkedHashMap?

Is an inputStream just basicaly a file, such as a txt file?

It is this line of code particularly confusing me:

```
Pairs.put(currentLine, processName(currentLine));
```

ReadSurnames:

```
/**
     * Reads the surnames from the InputStream that was supplied on object
     * creation
     */
    public void readSurnames() {
        String currentLine;
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(inputStream);

        while (scanner.hasNext()) {
            currentLine = scanner.nextLine();
            Pairs.put(currentLine, processName(currentLine));
        }

        try {
            inputStream.close();
            scanner.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err
                    .println("An error occured closing the input stream and scanner");
        }
    }
```

Process Name:

```
/**
     * Takes an initial name and processed to produce a phonetic version that
     * can be compared against other processed names
     * 
     * @param name
     *            The original name unprocessed name
     * @return The phonetic equivalent of the input name
     */
    public String processName(String name) {

        name = processNonAlphabetic(name);
        name = processDiscardedLetters(name);
        name = processEquivalentLetters(name);
        name = processDuplicateEquivalentLetters(name);

        return name;
    }
```

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html

Comment: `LinkedHashMap` maintain the order in which the items are added in it.

Comment: May be it should be in reverse order of key-value `Pairs.put(currentLine, processName(currentLine));`

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#put(K, V)

Answer (score 0):

For each line, it's mapping the original line to a processed version of the line, so later, you can access the processed version if you have the original.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean?